# Attempting to Write an Event Log on Success if on error write another one saying that it had failed

Tags: powershell, active-directory

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$Content = Get-Content C:\SMS\sms.txt -TotalCount 1 
ForEach ($Payroll in ($Content )) { 
    Get-ADUser -Identity "$Payroll" -Properties LockedOut | Select-Object LockedOut 

    If ($true) {$true -ne $false} 
    Unlock-ADAccount $Payroll 

    If ($true) {$true -ne $false}
    Write-EventLog -LogName "ADUnlock" -Source ADUnlock -EntryType Information -Message "AD account Successfully unlocked $Payroll" -Category 1 -EventId "12"

    If ($false) {$false -ne $true} 
    Write-EventLog -LogName "ADUnlock" -Source ADUnlock -EntryType Information -Message "AD account Attempted to unlock but failed $Payroll" -Category 1 -EventId "12" 
}
```

I am attempting to Write to the event log on success and error using the $true and the $false booleans but it is writing the two event logs despite the success or error, I have tried different variations of the code by using $LASTEXITCODE but then realized that it is for Win32 applications not for PowerShell Command lets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're doing with those `if` statements but I think you might want something like this:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$Content = Get-Content C:\SMS\sms.txt -TotalCount 1 
ForEach ($Payroll in ($Content )) { 
    $res = Get-ADUser -Identity "$Payroll" -Properties LockedOut | Select-Object LockedOut 
    If (!res) {continue} 

    Unlock-ADAccount $Payroll
    if ($?) {
        Write-EventLog -LogName "ADUnlock" -Source ADUnlock -EntryType Information -Message "AD account Successfully unlocked $Payroll" -Category 1 -EventId 12
    }
    else {
        Write-EventLog -LogName "ADUnlock" -Source ADUnlock -EntryType Information -Message "AD account Attempted to unlock but failed $Payroll" -Category 1 -EventId 12
    }
}
```

Thing is, I'm not sure what the type of `LockedOut` is. I'm assuming a Boolean here.

Comment: `LockedOut` Is An ADProperty I'll Give it a go.

I am attempting to write an event log on success and also on error.